# Ruby on Rails server and Rubymine IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, localhost, rubymine

So this time I did my research because of the downvoters...
My question is following.
I am using "Rubymine IDE" for development of Rails application on Win 10 PC, but I can't connect to rails server. I have tried connecting through console, and localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.3000 and 127.0.0.1.3000 but none of them do not work. I have tried creating the project file through console and then running server and it still doesn't work. I have XAMPP installed and that works perfectly fine. I have tried Firefox, Chrome and Edge for browsers. I am using commands such as ruby -s and rails -s and start rails server or ruby server, on the command rails -s I just get list of commands in the console and no results. I really need to get this thing working. I do not know if I need some extra commands to be typed or something else???
I can't add images to my posts yet, bu here is the list of gems I have on my PC 
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.1.4)
actionmailer (5.1.4)
actionpack (5.1.4)
actionview (5.1.4)
activejob (5.1.4)
activemodel (5.1.4)
activerecord (5.1.4)
activesupport (5.1.4, 4.2.5)
addressable (2.5.2)
arel (8.0.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
bindex (0.5.0)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.16.0)
byebug (9.1.0)
capybara (2.15.4)
childprocess (0.8.0)
coffee-rails (4.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
crass (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
erubi (1.7.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
ffi (1.9.18 x64-mingw32)
globalid (0.4.1)
i18n (0.9.1, 0.8.1)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
jbuilder (2.7.0)
json (default: 2.0.4, 1.8.6)
loofah (2.1.1)
mail (2.7.0)
method_source (0.9.0)
mini_mime (0.1.4)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0, 2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.3, 5.10.1)
multi_json (1.12.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.1.0)
nokogiri (1.8.1 x64-mingw32)
openssl (default: 2.0.5)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
public_suffix (3.0.0)
puma (3.10.0)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-test (0.7.0)
rails (5.1.4)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.4)
rake (12.2.1, 12.0.0)
rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
rb-inotify (0.9.10)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
sass (3.5.3)
sass-listen (4.0.0)
sass-rails (5.0.6)
selenium-webdriver (3.7.0)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.13 x64-mingw32)
test-unit (3.2.3)
thor (0.20.0)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.8)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
tzinfo (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
tzinfo-data (1.2017.3)
uglifier (3.2.0)
web-console (3.5.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
xpath (2.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a specific versions of gems installed for Ruby and Rails to work? If not try to install using

```
gem install ruby #This will install latest version of ruby
```

and for reference, can you post an image or something which specifies what is happening when you type `rails s`

Update:

```
bundle install
```

This should install all the missing gems and your server should be up and running!

Comment: sorry, I can not add images, I have posted the list of gems, but it doesn't look nice

Comment: on version are latest ruby 2.4. something and rails 5.1

Comment: Go inside project directory and do `bundle install` and then try `rails s`. I don't see any issues unless there are gem's version conflicts on your machine.

Comment: Thank You so much. I t is working now I thing. I t seems issue was when I have created the project through Rubymine it did not install few of these gems ans similar, it seems I have to go to every project through console and do these installations.

Comment: rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.2-p198), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

Comment: I t seems I am using 'Puma' does this means it is working now, and if you are familiar with Rubymine, can I type bundle install in Rubymine provided console inside the IDE

Comment: Yes you can do bundle install in the Rubymine provided console because basically if you see in the console, the working directory is your project's directory which you'd access through command prompt or terminal. And I am glad that it worked!

Comment: And Puma is a Ruby web server built for concurrency, so it seems to be working now based on your response.

Comment: If your problem is fixed then it would be appreciated if you can accept this answer! I put an update in my answer.